# Eclipse giving errors whenever I try to export to executable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export, executable-jar

I'm trying to export a small program that I have made in Eclipse Indigo today to an executable, however, every time I do so one of two problems occur. The program uses one resource which I was hoping to put inside of the JAR but Eclipse will not put in the executable jar no matter which option I tick when I export or which folder the resource is in - the first problem!

The second problem is that whenever I tell eclipse to "Extract required libraries into generated JAR" I receive the following error when I double click on the executable Jar:

> Could not find the main class: main.Launcher. Program will exit.

I don't suppose that the second problem is too much of an issue at the minute but the first one is extremely frustrating so I would appreciate any help or advice. Thanks in advance.

(Strangely, and even more frustrating, if I go through the same process with a project I made a while ago with a previous version of Eclipse it works perfectly.)

**The folder structure of the project is as follows:**

In the project folder there are the following directories `.settings`, `bin`, `src` as default. I have put the resource, which is a `png` in the `bin` folder but I have also tried it in the `src` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would like to thank Mike (marksml) for being so helpful and attempting to provide a solution for my problem. Unfortunately, his answer did not work for me!

I began to look at all of my previous projects and noticed that the one I was having trouble with was the odd one out (because it was the only one that didn't work) and the factor that made it the odd one out, I found to be the JRE system library version. The project was using the JavaSE-1.7 library but when I changed it to the JavaSE-1.6 like my other projects were using it miraculously worked and exported flawlessly! I'm still curious as to why this is the case, but at least I have it working now...

With thanks and kind regards, Andy

Answer (score 1):

Can you give some details?

What is the structure of your eclipse project?
Of what type is the resource?

More important where in the project structure resides the resource file?
Is the folder of that resource file included as a source folder ? (seems to be a prerequiste to get exported to the jar)

Is it copied over to the bin folder when the project is built?

Many Thanks
Michael

Update: 
I have built a very simple java project 1 Java class with a main method and put a sample png file in the source folder. I refreshed the project to have the png visible in the project, then I cleaned the project to have it build again, then I ran the Main class inside eclipse. This will give you a run configuration when exporting throught the wizard. Thereafter I exported the complete project as "runnable jar", selected the run configuration and selected "Copy required libraries in a sub-folder next to the generated JAR". The png was included and the Main class was found. The executable JAR could be executed.

(Environment: Eclipse Indigo R1, Ubuntu, JDK 6)

You might want to play through the complete sequence of steps I went through. Maybe eclipse just did not pick up a file or other updates.

regards, Mike

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please see my edit on the original question. That is really the only other information I can think of.

Comment: Hi Andy, I added some issue analysis details. Please see above in my previous answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (+1) again. Unfortunately, I didn't help solve the problem so I decided to investigate the matter a little further myself - please see my answer.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for providing the solution details after figuring them out. Have a good week.